# Calling a .java class or creating an object of a java class whose name matches with a String

Tags: java, json

I am creating a mail merge service which accepts a JSON object and populates a freemarker template with data in it.

In the process, I am using a library that creates a Pojo from the json. I provide the name for the pojo that is to be created
Now I want to use the pojo that has been created to set the data in the freemarker template. 
But I am not sure how to create object of the pojo class whose name would match with the string?

Has anyone done anything like this before?
I am using java 6.

Thanks,
Madhavee

Comment: what was you try? please add your code

Comment: `Class.forName("com.mypackage.MyClassName").newInstance()`

Comment: Hi Jesper, I tried this way. But I think before this line of code I should have the class loaded in the class path. Just in the previous step to this I am creating the java file dynamically. As a result it throws  ClassNotFoundException. Can you tell me how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

this might help:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html

```
 class NetworkClassLoader extends ClassLoader {
     String host;
     int port;

     public Class findClass(String name) {
         byte[] b = loadClassData(name);
         return defineClass(name, b, 0, b.length);
     }

     private byte[] loadClassData(String name) {
         // load the class data from the connection
          . . .
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to use JSON in Java is using Google's GSON library. It's really simple to use and I found that it was much easier to create the object template to match the GSON. They have a few tutorials on their website which might be of help to you.